# Excel VBA To Process and Forward Emails Causing "Out of memory" Error

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I hope someone can help- I'm hitting the dreaded "Out of memory or system resources" error with some code running in Excel and working with Outlook; from which the error originates.

Short description is it runs through a list of emails looking in the body/subject for a reference. If it finds it, it forwards the email item with the reference in the subject. MWE below; I'm not very experienced handling Outlook objects but I've spent nearly two hours trying different things with no luck. I can't use the GetTable() function since it doesn't include Body text data as far as I know (working off [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865868.aspx)), unless you can somehow add columns to include the body text?

If I run it in a freshly-opened Outlook session with only a dozen items it isn't a problem but I need it to work on hundreds of emails in one pop. Banging my head against a wall here. Thanks so much in advance!

```
Private Sub processMWE(ByVal oParent As Outlook.MAPIFolder)
        Dim thisMail As Outlook.MailItem
        Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
        Dim emailindex As Integer
        Dim folderpath As String
        Dim refandType As Variant
        Dim fwdItem
        Set myItems = oParent.Items
        folderpath = oParent.folderpath

        'Starting at row 2 on the current sheet
        i = 2

        With myItems
            'Data output to columns in Excel
            For emailindex = 1 To .Count
                Set thisMail = .Item(emailindex)

                'i takes row value
                Cells(i, 1).Value = folderpath
                Cells(i, 2).Value = thisMail.Subject + " " + thisMail.Body
                Cells(i, 3).Value = thisMail.SenderEmailAddress
                Cells(i, 4).Value = thisMail.ReceivedTime
                Cells(i, 6).Value = thisMail.Categories

                'Reference from body/subject and a match type (integer)
                refandType = extractInfo(Cells(i, 2))

                'This is the reference
                Cells(i, 5).Value = refandType(0)

                'And this is the match type.
                Select Case refandType(1)
                Case 1, 2
                    'do nothing
                Case Else
                    'For these match types, fwd the message
                    Set fwdItem = thisMail.Forward
                    fwdItem.Recipients.Add "#####@###"
                    fwdItem.Subject = Cells(i, 5) & " - " & thisMail.Subject
                    fwdItem.Send
                    'Edit original message category label
                    thisMail.Categories = "Forwarded"
                    thisMail.Save
                    'Note in spreadsheet
                    Cells(i, 7).Value = "Forwarded"
                    End If
                End Select
                i = i + 1
            Next
        End With
End Sub
```

**Edit**: New development: not only is it always hanging on the same line of code (thisMail.Body) it's actually doing it for specific mail items?! If I give it a batch of one of these problem messages it hangs immediately. Could it be something to do with character encoding or message length? Something that means thisMail.Body won't work that triggers a resources error?

Answer (score 1):

***Reason of the problem:***

You are creating items without releasing them from memory -with these lines-

```
        For emailindex = 1 To .Count
            Set thisMail = .Item(emailindex)
```

***Solution***

Release the objects once you are done with them

```
 End Select
                i = i + 1
 Set thisMail = Nothing           
 Next
        End With
```

***Common language explanation***

In this scenario, think about VBA as a waiter, you are telling it that you are going to give some dishes to serve to the customers, you are giving all of them to it, but you never tell it to release them to the table, at one point, it will not be able to handle any more dishes ("Out of memory")

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't seem to fix the problem :(

Comment: That's odd, try to add Set myItems = Nothing too and let me know if that helps

Comment: See edit above: I don't think it's actually a memory issue at all, it seems to be something within the body of specific emails that's causing the exception??

Comment: By any chance, the length when it hangs is above [255 character limit](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)?

Comment: Character limit doesn't seem to affect it: However it only hangs on items which are archived. Not all of them, but some of them. Opening the item and then reading it within the script works fine.

Comment: That's odd, I'm not sure how to solve it nor what to take as approach! I'm sorry, perhaps, could be some allocation error? If it works if you give some time, you may try with [application wait or sleep](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-wait-and-sleep-functions/)